# Shutil Copy prefixing a filename without reason

Tags: python, pandas, shutil

I am copying some files from one directory to another, based on whether they are .xlsx files. There are about 50 files which it copies which has been a smooth weekly process but now it is copying one of the files and adding a ~$ prefix to the filename, as well as copying over the file correctly. This ~$ file is also corrupt meaning when I read the file in pandas it comes up with an error.

I have this code below which is the copy paste, the file which it prefixes is Line Status_WCH.xlsx, it moves it over to the new directory but as two files, one with the correct filename the other is ~$Line Status_WCH.xlsx.

Is anyone aware of a cause to this?

```
for filename in os.listdir(getdirectory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        try:
            book = os.path.join(getdirectory + filename)
            print (book)
            shutil.copy(book, putdirectory)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            errorbook = filename
        except OSError:
            print(str(errorbook) + " Workbook in use")
            pass
```

This is what crashes out when trying to read the xlsx workbook, with the error

xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x15Packia '

```
if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        try:
            fName = os.path.join(homedir + filename)
            print (fName)

            fBase = os.path.basename(fName)
            fRaw = os.path.splitext(fBase)[0]

            df = pd.read_excel(fName)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `os.path.join(getdirectory,filename)` instead of `os.path.join(getdirectory + filename)`?

Comment: Hmm, always worked with + ?

Comment: but then what is the use of `os.path.join(..)`? The idea is that you add a path separator in between, so that `os.path.join('foo', 'bar')`, is `foo/bar` on a Unix-like system, and probably something else (as usual) on a Windows system.

Comment: Guess no reason, I'm relatively new to coding so though was needed to join path names